# What is a real life cycle of WCF OData service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm developing server application with several WCF OData services hosted (C# 4.0, VS2010).
I'm observing quite strange behavior of services and can't find any documentation on it that describes things I see in my application.

When client of services breaks connection for some reason, services go to Faulted state as I expect. But they still continue to work properly (they accept connections from new clients without issues and continue to serve data as expected - all this in Faulted state of corresponding DataServiceHosts).

If I increase concurrent clients number sometimes one of the services with most simultaneous connections silently stops working. It returns "Endpoint not found" message if I try to open its URL in browser. There are no exceptions or other visible symptoms I could use to dig into this. It simply stops silently. Other services with less number of concurrent clients continue to work without issues despite of Faulted state. Sometimes huge concurrent access doesn't trigger this silent death of the service and it continue to work properly.

Another one strange fact. When I switch on WCF tracing, I can't reproduce silent service stopping. It simply works perfect. So I can't use WCF tracing to investigate the source of the problem.

Can anyone explain me what is a real WCF OData service life cycle? Why it continue to work with Faulted state? What may be the reason for the silent stop? Should WCF OData services be restarted each time after client breaks connection?